# SAML : How to implement SSO (Single sign on ) for an web application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, opensaml

I have searched a lot for a good documentation on how to implement SSO as I am a beginner in this field. But got confused with documentations, available online. Is there any documentation that can help me directing :
How to Create/configure IDP , SP, how to implement SSO?

My web application uses, Java 8, angular JS , JSP, Spring ( with annotations), Hibernet, Maven, JBOSS.

Appreciate your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of broad which is hard to give a definitive answer. Perhaps knowing better about what to research may help. Please let me try:

1. Your web application will be an SP. Thus, you don't need to research for how to implement an IdP.
2. You will need at least 1 IdP to test SSO for your application. Therefore, find out what IdP you want to use and research for how to set it up as well as how to configure a service provider trust against it.
3. What is the protocol you want to use for SSO? Is it SAML 2.0, WSFed, OAuth2, OpenId Connect or something else? Pick one.
4. Research a good library that you can use to implement the SP role for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned Java and Spring so typically you are looking at Spring Security and SAML.

If that's the case. then you need to implement a client side SAML stack.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).